# How to prevent postback of ASP.NET page from resetting classes on button

Tags: javascript, webforms

In my ASP.NET webform I have a series of HTML buttons and their initial state is disabled except for 1, when the initial button which is enabled is clicked I use JavaScript to remove the disabled class from the first disabled button but then ASP.NET triggers a postback and the button is reset to it's disabled state.  I've tried adding preventdefault to stop this from happening but it does not work.  How can I prevent the postback from resetting my button to disabled?

This is the code for my buttons

```
<li><button id="viewOrderAuto" class="btn btn-default btn-primary" type="button">1. View Order</button></li>
            <li><button id="addRecItmAuto" class="btn btn-default disabled" type="button">2. Update Quantities</button></li>
            <li><button id="receiveAuto" class="btn btn-default disabled" type="button">3. Save Changes</button></li>
```

This is the click event of the first button

```
    $("#viewOrderAuto")
    .click(function (e) {
        AutoRunthrough.viewOrder();
    });
```

This is the code which calls the function to remove the disabled class

```
        viewOrder: function (e) {
        $('.nav-tabs a[href="#receiving"]').tab('show');
        var btnRow = $("#MainContent_OrderListGrid tbody").find("a:first");
        if (typeof btnRow != 'undefined')
            eval(btnRow.attr('href'));
        AutoRunthrough.removeDisable($("#addRecItmAuto"));

    }
```

Finally the function which removes the class

```
        removeDisable: function (element) {
        element.removeClass("disabled");
        element.preventDefault();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't keep states maintained. Therefore when page refreshes whole script renders again. You can keep a hidden value in aspx.cs file and set it through javaScript. Then conditioning on it you can Disable buttons.

.aspx.cs file

```
    <asp:HiddenField ID="buttonCondition" runat="server" />

   <script>
    var buttonCondition= '#<%= buttonCondition.ClientID %>';
    </script>
```

javaScript file

```
     $("#viewOrderAuto")
.click(function (e) {
    AutoRunthrough.viewOrder();
   $(buttonCondition).val(true)
});

if($(buttonCondition).val()==true)
   then do here what you want
```